# Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller in android mapV2

Tags: android, google-maps

In my android application i have used mapV2, its all working fine but when i have changed my package name yesterday i cant able to get google map it always shows white screen

Note : i have generated new API key with new SHA1 and new Package name

i got this log

```
Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh
```

check it out my menifest :

```
<permission
        android:name="package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />



<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD0RF9KFHTW6CYNYoj5lFDkcPssb0VHxc4" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: I think it `Google Play services` version problem, you need to totally uninstall your app on the phone and then reinstall it.